# E10 errors in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I have encounter many E10 error while invoking vim:

```
Error detected while processing 
/home/wzming/.vim/bundle/vundle/autoload/vundle.vim:^[[?  25l^[[J^M

3 line    8:^[[J^M
4 E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &^[[J^M
5 line   11:^[[J^M
6 E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &^[[J^M
7 line   14:^[[J^M
8 E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &^[[J^M
```

My `.vimrc` is as follows:

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()

"let Vundle manage Vundle
" required! 
Bundle 'gmarik/vundle'

" My Bundles here:
"
" original repos on github(VERIFIED)
Bundle 'scrooloose/nerdtree.git'
Bundle 'brookhong/cscope.vim'
Bundle 'ervandew/snipmate.vim'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-surround'
Bundle 'othree/xml.vim'
Bundle 'ervandew/supertab'
Bundle 'kien/ctrlp.vim'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/vim-easymotion'
"Bundle 'corntrace/bufexplorer'
Bundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Bundle 'xolox/vim-misc'
Bundle 'xolox/vim-session'
Bundle 'Lokaltog/powerline'
Bundle 'majutsushi/tagbar'
Bundle 'scrooloose/syntastic'
"Bundle 'mbbill/code_complete'
"Bundle 'vim-scripts/grep.vim'

" original repos on github(UNVERIFIED)
" vim-scripts repos
"Bundle 'javacomplete'
"Bundle 'L9'
"Bundle 'FuzzyFinder'
" non github repos
"Bundle 'git://git.wincent.com/command-t.git'
" ...

filetype plugin indent on     " required!
" vundle Brief help
" :BundleList          - list configured bundles
" :BundleInstall(!)    - install(update) bundles
" :BundleSearch(!) foo - search(or refresh cache first) for foo
" :BundleClean(!)      - confirm(or auto-approve)
"removal of unused bundles

" GENERAL CONFIG
" Use Vim settings, rather then Vi settings (much better!).

" ================ General Config ====================
set number                      "Line numbers are good
set backspace=indent,eol,start  "Allow backspace in insert mode
set history=1000                "Store lots of :cmdline history
set showcmd                     "Show incomplete cmds down the bottom
set showmode                    "Show current mode down the bottom
set gcr=a:blinkon0              "Disable cursor blink
set visualbell                  "No sounds
set autoread                    "Reload files changed outside vim
"set autochdir                   "Auto change into the active dir
" Caution: this can not change the leader key used by c.vim

" This makes vim act like all other editors, buffers can
" exist in the background without being in a window.
" http://items.sjbach.com/319/configuring-vim-right
set hidden

" ================ Command mapping ====================
"nmap <leader>p :!python %<CR>
nmap <leader>p :! perl %<CR>
nmap <leader>s :! /bin/bash %<CR>
" mark.vim
"nmap n \*
"nmap N \#
"nmap nn \/
"nmap NN \?

" nmap <leader>s<leader>d :!/bin/bash %<CR>
map<F5> :cn <cr>
map<F6> :cp <cr>
"nmap <leader>t<leader>a :!cscope -Rbq
    \ && cs add cscope.out
    \ && ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q . <CR>

"for cpp ctags
nmap <leader>t<leader>p :!ctags -R --exclude=".git"
    \ --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iafksS --extra=+qf . <CR>
"for java ctags
nmap <leader>t<leader>j :!ctags -R --exclude=".git"
    \ --Java-kinds=+p --fields=+iafksS --extra=+qf . <CR>
"for c ctags
nmap <leader>t<leader>n :!ctags -R --exclude=".git"
    \ --c-kinds=+p --extra=+qf . <CR>

"cscope tags
nmap <leader>t<leader>c :call RebuildCscope() <CR>
map <F3> :NERDTreeToggle <cr>
map <F2> :TagbarToggle<cr>

"turn on syntax highlighting
syntax on

" ================ Search Settings  =================
set incsearch        "Find the next match as we type the search
set hlsearch         "Hilight searches by default
set viminfo='100,f1  "Save up to 100 marks, enable capital marks

" ================ Turn Off Swap Files ==============
set noswapfile
set nobackup
set nowb

" ================ Persistent Undo ==================
" Keep undo history across sessions, by storing in file.
" Only works all the time.
"silent !mkdir ~/.vim/backups > /dev/null 2>&1
"set undodir=~/.vim/backups
"set undofile

" ================ Indentation ======================
set autoindent
set smartindent
set smarttab
set shiftwidth=4
set softtabstop=2
set tabstop=2
set expandtab

" Display tabs and trailing spaces visually
set list listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:·

"set nowrap       "Don't wrap lines
set linebreak    "Wrap lines at convenient points

" ================ Folds ============================
set foldmethod=indent   "fold based on indent
set foldnestmax=3       "deepest fold is 3 levels
set nofoldenable        "dont fold by default

" ================ Completion =======================

set wildmode=list:longest,full
set wildmenu                "enable ctrl-n and ctrl-p to scroll thru matches
set wildignore=*.o,*.obj,*~ "stuff to ignore when tab completing
set wildignore+=*vim/backups*
set wildignore+=*sass-cache*
set wildignore+=*DS_Store*
set wildignore+=vendor/rails/**
set wildignore+=vendor/cache/**
set wildignore+=*.gem
set wildignore+=log/**
set wildignore+=tmp/**
set wildignore+=*.png,*.jpg,*.gif

" ================ Scrolling ========================
set scrolloff=8         "Start scrolling when we're 8 lines away from margins
"set sidescrolloff=15   " disable side scroll
"set sidescroll=1

" ================ GENERAL CONFIG OVER========================

" ================ Configuration for plugins ========================
"" cscope

"set cscopequickfix=s-,c-,d-,i-,t-,e-

if filereadable("cscope.out")
    cs add cscope.out
endif
nmap <C-\>s :cs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-\>g :cs find g <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-\>c :cs find c <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-\>t :cs find t <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-\>e :cs find e <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-\>f :cs find f <C-R>=expand("<cfile>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-\>i :cs find i ^<C-R>=expand("<cfile>")<CR>$<CR>
nmap <C-\>d :cs find d <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>

nmap <C-@>s :vert scs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-@>g :vert scs find g <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-@>c :vert scs find c <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-@>t :vert scs find t <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-@>e :vert scs find e <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-@>f :vert scs find f <C-R>=expand("<cfile>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-@>i :vert scs find i ^<C-R>=expand("<cfile>")<CR>$<CR>
nmap <C-@>d :vert scs find d <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>

nmap <C-@><C-@>s :scs find s <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-@><C-@>g :scs find g <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-@><C-@>c :scs find c <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-@><C-@>t :scs find t <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-@><C-@>e :scs find e <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-@><C-@>f :scs find f <C-R>=expand("<cfile>")<CR><CR>
nmap <C-@><C-@>i :scs find i ^<C-R>=expand("<cfile>")<CR>$<CR>
nmap <C-@><C-@>d :scs find d <C-R>=expand("<cword>")<CR><CR>

" vimwiki
"let g:vimwiki_use_mouse = 1
map <leader>dd :VimwikiDeleteLink
"更改当前页的名称 
map <Leader>rr :VimwikiRenameLink
let g:vimwiki_list = [{'path': '~/PersonalData/vimwiki/', }]
"let g:vimwiki_camel_case = 0
" 标记为完成的 checklist 项目会有特别的颜色
let g:vimwiki_hl_cb_checked = 1

"xml.vim
let g:xml_syntax_folding = 5
set foldmethod=syntax

"neocomplacache
""" " Use neocomplcache. 
""let g:neocomplcache_enable_at_startup = 1 
""" " Use smartcase. 
""let g:neocomplcache_enable_smart_case = 1 
""" " Use camel case completion. 
""let g:neocomplcache_enable_camel_case_completion = 1 
""" " Use underbar completion. 
""let g:neocomplcache_enable_underbar_completion = 1 
""" " Set minimum syntax keyword length. 
""let g:neocomplcache_min_syntax_length = 3 
""let g:neocomplcache_lock_buffer_name_pattern = '\*ku\*' 
""" AutoComplPop like behavior. 
""let g:neocomplcache_enable_auto_select = 1 

" OmniCppComplete
"set omnifunc=syntaxcomplete#Complete
"
"let OmniCpp_NamespaceSearch = 1
"let OmniCpp_GlobalScopeSearch = 1
"let OmniCpp_ShowAccess = 1
"let OmniCpp_ShowPrototypeInAbbr = 1 " show function parameters
"let OmniCpp_MayCompleteDot = 1 " autocomplete after .
"let OmniCpp_MayCompleteArrow = 1 " autocomplete after ->
"let OmniCpp_MayCompleteScope = 1 " autocomplete after ::
"let OmniCpp_SelectFirstItem = 1
"let OmniCpp_DisplayMode=1

"auto complete chars 
":inoremap ) ()<Esc>i
":inoremap { {}<Esc>i
":inoremap [ []<Esc>i
"":inoremap " ""<Esc>i
"":inoremap ' ''<Esc>i

"ctrlp 
let g:ctrlp_tabpage_position = 'ac'
" open file in new tab
let g:ctrlp_prompt_mappings = {
  \ 'AcceptSelection("e")': [],
  \ 'AcceptSelection("t")': ['<cr>', '<c-m>'],
  \ }
let g:ctrlp_max_files=0
let g:ctrlp_max_height = 15
let g:ctrlp_max_depth = 40
"ignore some files
set wildignore+=*/tmp/*,*.so,*.swp,*.zip,*.jpg,*.gif,*.png,*.pdf,*.class
let g:ctrlp_custom_ignore = {
  \ 'dir':  '\.git$\|\.hg$\|\.svn$',
  \ 'file': '\.png$\|\.gif$\|\.jpg$|\.class$|\.o$',
  \ }

" supertab
let g:SuperTabNoCompleteAfter=['^', ',', '\s']

"session
let g:session_autosave = 'yes'
let g:session_autoload = 'no'

"powerline
set rtp+=/home/wzming/.local/lib/python2.7/
    \ site-packages/powerline/bindings/vim/
" Always show statusline
set laststatus=2
"  Use 256 colours (Use this setting only on supporting terminals)
set t_Co=256

" color scheme
colorscheme molokai

" tagbar
let g:tagbar_left = 1

"Syntastic
"Enable active checking for all file types
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'active',
            \ 'active_filetypes': [],
            \ 'passive_filetypes': ['java'] }
" supress all the warning, only error will display
let g:syntastic_quiet_warnings=1
highlight SyntasticErrorSign guifg=white guibg=red
"status line
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*
"Enable checking on file opening
let g:syntastic_check_on_open=1

" function list
function RebuildCscope()
    cs kill 0
    !rm -rf cscope.*
    !cscope -Rbq --exclude=".git"
    cs add cscope.out
endfunction

"Compile And Run Current C file
function RunCurCFile()
    wa
    !gcc % -o %:r.out && ./%:r.out
endfunction
```

Comment: Try adding `set nocompatible` to the top of the file. (Although it shouldn't be necessary)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The help for E10 (`:h E10`) says use `set nocp` to get rid of the error.

```
                                                        E10 
  \\ should be followed by /, ? or &

A command line started with a backslash or the range of a command contained a
backslash in a wrong place.  This is often caused by command-line continuation
being disabled.  Remove the 'C' flag from the 'cpoptions' option to enable it.
Or use ":set nocp".
```

So just put `set nocompatible` (which is the long form of `set nocp`) at the top of the file